# Multiply two columns in Sql Stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a table Stock with

```
StockID   ItemID   Quantity   Price
```

now i want to select data some thing like this

```
StockID   ItemID   Quantity Price   TotalPrice(Quantity*Price)
```

i tried this

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SelectItemStock] 
@Item   int
as
BEGIN
    SELECT  Stock.*, (SELECT Quantity*Price FROM Stock) AS TotalPrice
    FROM    Stock
    WHERE   ItemID = @Item
END
```

but it gives me the error `Subquery returned more than 1 value.`

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you don't need to do a subquery to get the product of the two columns, just multiply it directly,

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SelectItemStock] 
@Item   int
as
BEGIN
    SELECT  Stock.*, 
            (Quantity*Price) AS TotalPrice
    FROM    Stock
    WHERE   ItemID = @Item
END
```